# Swift, GCD and CoreData error: error: NULL _cd_rawData but the object is not being turned into a fault

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I have written an some code which ready async data from CoreData. I've followed the tips being around in the internet, but sometimes I get the following error:
CoreData: error: NULL _cd_rawData but the object is not being turned into a fault

Here is my code which performs the read of an object from core data and which throws the error.

```
func getObject(forKey: String, answer: (Bool, NSObject?) -> ()) {
    let pMOC = initPrivateMOC()
    pMOC.performBlock({
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("CacheObject", inManagedObjectContext: pMOC)

        fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier == %@", forKey)


        do {
            let result = try self.managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [CacheObject]
            var answerObject:NSObject?
            if !result.isEmpty {
                if let coObject = result[0].object {
                    if let retrievedObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(coObject) as? NSObject {
                        answerObject = retrievedObject
                    }
                }
            }
            answer(true, answerObject)
        } catch {
            answer(false, nil)
            fatalError("[CacheManager:getObject] -> Fehler beim Lesen von Daten")
        }
    })
}
```

At `if let coObject = result[0].object` the error accures. Here are the function of getting the private MOC:

```
init() {
    let coreDataHandler = CoreDataHandler(identifier: "MK.SimpleCacheStore", ressource: "SimpleCache")
    self.managedObjectContext = coreDataHandler.getMOC()

}

func initPrivateMOC() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let pMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    pMOC.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext

    return pMOC
}
```

And also the call from a class above which gets accessed by for requests:

```
public func get(forKey: String, answer: (Bool, NSObject?) -> ()) {
    if let cam = cacheManager {
        if let cachedObj = cam.getObjectFromCache(forKey) {
            print("[SCManager:get] -> Objekt aus NSCache geladen")
            answer(true, cachedObj)
        } else {
            if let cdm = coreDataManger {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), {
                    cdm.getObject(forKey, answer: {
                        success, data in
                        //Enable Entry in NSCache
                        if let cdData = data {
                            cam.saveObjectToCache(forKey, object: cdData)
                            print("[SCManager:get] -> Objekt nach nicht auffinden gecacht")
                        }
                        print("[SCManager:get] -> Objekt nicht in NSCache, deshalb aus CoreData")
                        answer(success, data)
                    })
                })
            }
        }
}
```

Do you know the problem or find any bug or problem in the way I've implemented GCD and CoreData a hint would be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I haven't add the private MOC in my requests. So the solution is to use *pMOC* for *fetchRequest()*